# FFmpeg: How to replace a video stream in a video file with multiple audio streams?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a video webm-Fle with multiple audio streams (17 languages) and want to replace the video stream with a newer one without re-encoding the audio.
Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`-map` option](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options) to select the desired streams and `-c copy` to [stream copy](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) these streams:

```
ffmpeg -i newvideo.webm -i 17_languages.webm -map 0:v -map 1:a -c copy output.webm
```

Add the output option `-shortest` if you want the output to end when the shortest stream ends.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution using [map](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map)

I tool the audio from the first input `-map 0:1` and the video fromthe second input `-map 1:0`

This resolved my issue.